# How to debug or log ASP.net pages

Tags: asp.net, debugging, asp-classic, script-debugging

First off I am not a programmer or else I should probably know how to do this already.  I have a situation where I am receiving an MS Jscript runtime 800a1391 indicating whereClause is undefined.  I am fairly certain in previous portion of the ASP page it is attempting to gather values and is most likely failing to return values or is returning something like a null that is later breaking the script on this line.

Here is the line it is failing on:

```
{
    url += "&chartType=" +chartType + "&selClause=" + selClause + "&whereTrendTimeClause="  + whereClause + "&TrendTypeForReport=" + TrendType + "&ReportDisplayType=" + Request("ReportDisplayType") + showModes + "&whereProtocolClause=" + protocolClause + "&groupClause=" + groupClause + "&joinClause=" + joinClause + "&groupIDClause=" + groupIDClause;
}
```

What I am trying to figure is how to output (either to text) or even printed to screen the returns each time the whereClause does something within this page.  Even if I have to manually enter some bit of code for each instance of whereClause that is fine.  I am not looking for an easy solution just a method that works and returns what I need which is a very verbose output.  The reason a verbose output is needed is I can compare a working environment vs a non-working one.  I just need to get the "logging" to work first.

thanks,

Comment: I've found that sometimes the actual error may be on one of the preceding lines - could you post a little more code from before/after for context? Also, are you using asp-classic or asp.net? They are two very different technologies and will yield different answers... re-tagging appropriately would help.

Answer (score 0):

To monitor your variable and see what your variable have you can use Google Chrome, and opening by the Console (right click on the page, click Inspect Element, then Select Console) you can see the errors that you have on page.

And you can use the `console.log()` to write on it from your javascript code.

You can learn more on [this tutorial - Debug the web](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will take a look at the tutorial.  Unfortunately, this interface appears to use a bunch of embedded pages and also was not formatted with Chrome in mind so it does not display properly so most of the links are not accessible due to them all being piled on top of each other.

Comment: @KazrathThatsMe There are similar tools on Netscape, try out netscape the same way. I am sorry but I have quit IE, some years ago, is very slow and not help on development, thats why I do not know what are the commands there, but you can look at the same directions on IE site.

Comment: @KazrathThatsMe there are developer tools built in to IE8+, and a download to add them to IE6/7 if absolutely needed. Press F12 to get to them or click on "Developer Tools" on the Tools menu. If I remember right, on Win8 you will need to be in desktop mode to get access to them.